# Is a 166 point exam due in 30 mins too short?

Tags: ethics, exams, legal-issues, education

Our professor gave us a long exam worth 166 points. It was composed of 130 items 10 of which were identification and 120 were multiple choice. A lot of the questions required ethical analysis as out subject was ethics. He only gave us 30 mins to answer the exam. It this even legal?

Location: Philippines

Comment: Why would you think it illegal?

Comment: There is too little information here for any reasonable answer. The number of points assigned is impossible to evaluate without knowing the whole picture of the course. How it is graded is also an issue you don't address. Likewise the average difficulty of the questions. You are upset, but don't just rant here, please.

Comment: The number of points is irrelevant, it does not tell us anything about how challenging and time-demanding the questions actually are.

Comment: If you want a legal answer, try the Law SE. We are not the place to ask about whether it is legal or not.

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea what "points" mean here and I don't want to know. But in any case 120 multiple choice questions in 30 minutes means you have 15 seconds to tick each answer. Yes, that's too much, if you are expected to complete them all; even reading out all the questions could take longer.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, it's legal**

There is no law in the Philippines or elsewhere that dictates length of an exam or time limits on the exam.

Some professors purposefully give an exam that no one can finish and then grade on a curve.  That is possibly what happened here.

Comment: I don't know about the Philippines, but in some countries some profs have exams which are almost impossible and you have to pay the professor money to do a "possible" exam.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak specifically about the Philippines, but in no country I have come across does the law provide any special provisions for things that are and aren't allowed in Universities. This particularly applies to situations where any judge deciding on a matter would have to decide if a professor's judgement about matters within that professors subject expertise or on issues of pedagogy, as the professor will be regarded as being in a better place to know than the judge.

Exceptions to this exist in some countries for equality issues related to "protected characteristics", such as race, gender, sex, religion or disability. In other countries, universities are subject to general law about discrimination that might apply to specific situations.

However, unless discrimination is an issue (and there is no suggestion it is here), no country is going to have laws on what is and isn't a fair way to assess someone.